# Calendario con restricciones con HTML, JavaScript, CSS

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, html5

Necesito ayuda. Busco implementar un formulario en donde uno de los campos sea un calendario, el cual tenga las siguientes características:

**1)** Sábados y domingos deshabilitados.

**2)** Que no permita seleccionar fechas anteriores.

**3)** Como los envíos de los productos se hacen 48hs después de hacer el pedido, la idea es que, si hoy es Lunes, la primer fecha disponible sea desde el Miércoles en adelante.

He buscado por varios sitios de internet pero nadie logra darme la solución correcta. Lo mejor que pude encontrar es este calendario:

https://www.cssscript.com/minimal-inline-calendar-date-picker-vanilla-javascript/

Si alguien tiene conocimientos de cómo realizar esto, se los agradecería.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Damian puedes modificar tu pregunta? Es mas fácil de que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y  respondida si dejas un  [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Un saludo, con gusto dispuesto ayudar.

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford ahí agregué un link a una web con un calendario posible, pero lo que me está faltando es agregar esas restricciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, para hacer esto una opción que te recomiendo es [flatpickr.js](https://flatpickr.js.org), es un plugin bastante ligero y totalmente programable.

En esta respuesta no explico como instalarlo pero para guiarte en como podrías solventar el inconveniente con el plugin, te dejo el siguiente **código de ejemplo**:

```
    // Seleccionamos la  etiqueta que queremos convertir con el plugin:

$(".selector").flatpickr({

  // Agregamos nuestra configuracion deseada, en este caso solo haremos que no sean seleccionables los dias no deseados.

  // Con disable condicionamos que si date.getDay() es igual al dia de la semana no deseado, este se desactive. 

  "disable": [
    function(date) {
        // return true to disable
        return (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);

    }
  ]  

});
```

Aqui te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/denyncrawford/fzv51a2o/).

Y eso seria todo, te recomiendo que te des una pasada por la documentación ya que vale la pena, es un plugin bastante rico, sobre todo en información, ahí están todas sus funciones y también tienes algunos ejemplos.

> **NOTA**: Puedes trabajarlo en JQuery y en JavaScript Vanilla.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda, un saludo.

[CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/flatpickr)  -  [Documentación](https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Me va a servir mucho tu aporte